# How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?

Tags: python-telegram-bot

For example, bot has command `/set_coordinates`. It accept latitude and longitude, like this:

- Bot: Enter latitude
- User: 16.4353
- Bot: Enter longitude
- User: 140.4325

The thing is that bot receives only one coordinate per message, and to understand either it need to request latitude or longitude, it should remember previous message. For example:

```
latitude_was_set = False
latitude, longitude = 0, 0

def set_coordinates_handler(update: Update, context: Context):
    received_text = update.message.text
     
    # First coordinate
    if not self.latitude_was_set:
       latitude = float(received_text)
       self.latitude_was_set = True
    else:
       longitude = float(received_text)
```

It's simplified function without prints and other things to demonstrate that I **need** flag `latitude_was_self`. The problem is that I should store everything in a database,
because two user can have different `latitude_was_set` and variable inside python doesn't fit it. It seems to be inappropriate use of database to store a flag there. This problem becomes even bigger if I need to get more data in one command. Is there any other options instead of using database as a flag storage?

This question can be silly but it's my first bot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PTB provides two useful mechanisms for such usecases:

- [Storing data](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Storing-bot%2C-user-and-chat-related-data)
- [`ConversationHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/v13.15/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html), see also the [example](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/v13.x/examples#conversationbotpy)

Update:

The correspondings links for v20.x of `python-telegram-bot` are:

- [Storing data](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Storing-bot,-user-and-chat-related-data)
- [`ConversationHandler`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/telegram.ext.conversationhandler.html), see also the [example](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0b0/examples.html#examples-conversationbot)

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`