# Telegram Bot get as User Input previous message

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm experiencing a small issue with the library `python-telegram-bot`.
So this is my code:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, CallbackContext
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, ReplyKeyboardMarkup
from telegram import Update
from telegram import Bot
import telegram
import os
import datetime
import sqlite3
import traceback
import re
import data

def start(update, context):
    chatid = update.message.chat_id

    if data.user_exist(chatid) == True:
        update.message.reply_text('Choiche wallet', reply_markup=wallet_handler(chatid, update, context))
    if data.user_exist(chatid) == False:
        update.message.reply_text('Add wallet')
        add_wallet(chatid, update, context)

def wallet_handler(chatid, update, context):
    kb = []

    for w in data.fetch_wallet(chatid):
        s = w[0:10]
        kb.append([InlineKeyboardButton(s, callback_data=w)])
    kb.append([InlineKeyboardButton('Add Wallet', callback_data='add')])
    kb.append([InlineKeyboardButton('Delete Wallet', callback_data='delete')])
    
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(kb)

def add_wallet(chatid, update, context):
    regex = re.compile(r"/^(?:0x)[A-Z0-9]{15}$/")
    update.message.reply_text(text='Insert a wallet address please')
    address = update.message.text
    print(address)

    if re.fullmatch(regex, address):
        print('okay')
    else:
        print('nooo')
    return


def main():
   update= Updater('token', use_context=True)
   bot = Bot('token')
   disp=update.dispatcher

   disp.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))
   disp.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.regex('/^(?:0x)[A-Z0-9]{15}$/'), add_wallet, run_async=True))
   update.start_polling()
   update.idle()

if __name__=='__main__':
   main()
```

When the user send the `/start` command, the function `user_exist()` check a determined condition. If the function returns false, then the bot should wait for user input (triggering the function `add_wallet()`).

But when I try this code, the `add_wallet()` function takes as user input the previous message `/start` and doesn't wait for the user input.

How to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api) Also please remove the `py-telegram-bot-api` tag, which is for a different library

Comment: Everyone say tu use conv handler but i can't understand how to apply it in my context.