# How to reset callback_query value to receive multiple inputs in Python-Telegram-Bot

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

After the user clicks on one button, the `callback_query.data` is assigned a value and is no longer able to receive additional inputs and the while loop constantly runs with that value. I am not sure how to either reset the `callback_query.data` value or to request the user for an additional input.

I would like to receive multiple inputs from the user using InlineKeyboard and only continue to the run code when the user clicks on the `done` InlineKeyboardButton.

```
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(button_list)
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose the headers:', reply_markup=reply_markup)
    query = update.callback_query
    query_list = query.data.split(" ")
    while 'done' not in query_list:
        if query.data not in query_list:
            query_list.append(update.callback_query.data)
        else:
            pass
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(text="Your input has been updated!")
```

This line of code uses the Python-Telegram-Bot package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)

Comment: Correct, `update.callback_query` is an instance of `telegram.CallbackQuery`, not a `dict`. The point is that a callback function will only ever handle one update at a time, never more.
`CH` can very well be used with a dynamic number of inputs.

Comment: @CallMeStag I see! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

By using `ConversationHandler` and a while loop, I am able to receive a dynamic number of inputs.

```
def select(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    global reply_markup
    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(build_menu(button_list, n_cols=1))
    update.message.reply_text('Please choose the headers:', reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return SECOND


def display(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    query = update.callback_query
    global query_list
    query_list = query.data.split(" ")
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f"{query.data} is added as a column header")
    query.answer()
    query.edit_message_text(text="Select other headers or click Done to end the selection!", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return THIRD


def display_2(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int:
    query = update.callback_query
    while 'done' not in query_list:
        if query.data not in query_list and query.data != 'done':
            query_list.append(query.data)
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=f"{query.data} is added as a column header")
        elif query.data == 'done':
            break
        else:
            text = f"{query.data} is already added as a column header, choose another header or click Done to end the selection!"
            context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text=text)
        del update.callback_query.data
        return THIRD
    query.edit_message_text(text="I have received your input! Type /workout to receive your workout for today!")

    return ConversationHandler.END
```

As seen in `display_2` the while loop will bring the user back to the `THIRD` state of the conversation, which is `display_2`. I am not sure whether there is a more efficient way in doing this but this achieves my intent.

Comment: you can replace `while` with `if`