# python-telegram-bot handle message only after command

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to let bot send the message that i gave him by first sending `/send_m` command then it will ask for the message after that i write the message it will send it to other users, the problem is that message handler is running `send` function even if I didn't give it `/send_m` command how can i fix this issue?

```
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('send', send_m))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text,send))
updater.start_polling()
```

I'm handling messages and commands like this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've daclared a boolean variable and when i get the command it's been set to `True` and declared end function to set the boolean `False` when the function called and i put if statement for every message handled to check if send command has called.

Comment: did you self answered your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text,send & ~Filters.command, send))
```

You may notice that MessageHandler is used instead of CommandHandler. This is a more general handler that selects messages based off flags that you supply. In this case, it handles messages that contain text but **aren't commands**