# How to get input from a user after choosing an option from a menu in python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a telegram bot that has a menu of two options. I want the user to choose an option, then ask for a users input based on the menu option choice and do a mathematical operation.

Here is my code:

```
from telegram import *
from telegram.ext import *
from requests import *

updater = Updater(token="XXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

fun_one = "Function One"
fun_two = "Function Two"

allowedUsernames = ['XXX']


def startCommand(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    buttons = [[KeyboardButton(fun_one)], [
        KeyboardButton(fun_two)]]
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id,
                             text="Hi", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardMarkup(buttons))


def messageHandler(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    if update.effective_chat.username not in allowedUsernames:
        context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="You are not allowed to use this bot")
        return
    if fun_one in update.message.text:
        context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Please inter a number")
        # ask for user input, and then do an operation on it
    if fun_two in update.message.text:
        context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Please inter a number")
        # ask for user input, and the do an operation on it


dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", startCommand))
dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, messageHandler))

updater.start_polling()
```

My issue is I don't know how to read the users input depending on the menu's choice. I have put a comment in both locations.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Did you take a look into the python [input](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-input-function/amp/) function?

Comment: @Roxy My issue is not with the input, my issue is with how to do the operation on the input based on the menu option choice.

Comment: You could save the user input to a variable and pass it as an argument to the function called. Shouldn’t that work? What is the operation you want to carry in the input? Is it a function or calculations, etc?

Comment: The user input is coming from a user using the telegram bot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)