# Python Telegram Bot - send message only after user clicks on a inline button

Tags: python, automation, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am in the process of making a inline telegram bot and because I want to make sure users read the messages with the bot I want to force them to press a inline button I send them before it sends the next paragraph of text.

```
message = f"""Message
   
    """
    
        results = [
            InlineQueryResultArticle(
                id="ProveVerification",
                title="Message sent!",
                input_message_content=InputTextMessageContent("Please look for a message from the bot", parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN),
               
            )
        ]
        

        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.inline_query.from_user.id, text=message)
        update.inline_query.answer(results)
        button_check = types.InlineKeyboardButton('✅', callback_data='pressed')
        keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        keyboard.add(button_check)
        
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.inline_query.from_user.id, text='Confirm you read the message above by clicking on the button below', reply_markup=keyboard)

#if callback_data ='pressed' send another message
```

I know that I should make an if statement that checks if the callback_data is 'pressed', but I am stuck on that

I tried several methods of getting to the callback_data parameter, but they all resulted in the bot breaking, it sends the first message and then I get the default telegram message that the bot is broken

Comment: Is that a postback button? Does Telegram's bots API send postback-clicked events in the same webhook events as messages? https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#callbackquery

Comment: It looks like you're mixing the `python-telgeram-bot` library with some other library (`pyTelgeramBotAPI`?). I highly recommend to choose one linbrary and then stick to it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)