# Getting Error: "TypeError: object Message can't be used in 'await' expression" when trying to wait and get user input on Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

On telegram the bot is showing me the "reply keyboard" but nothing further happens as the below error gets raised

```
async def start (update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    reply_keyboard = [["A", "B", "C"]]
    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Select any one",
        reply_markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup(reply_keyboard, one_time_keyboard=True)
    )
      
def handle_inputs (update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    comd = update.message.text
    if (comd == '/start'): 
        asyncio.run(start(update, context))
    else:
        update.message.reply_text("Sorry '%s' is not a valid command" % update.message.text)
        
def main():
    updater = Updater(BOT_TOKEN, use_context=True)
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, handle_inputs))
    
    updater.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I am new to Telegram bot and have less knowledge for Async Functions. Any help will be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

I tried to understand more about co-routines but and not quite sure how to implement it here.
I am expecting couple of telegram features to implement like:

- wait for user to input something
- reply keyboard, inline keyboard, etc.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `python-telegram-bot`, but that looks like `update.message.reply_text` is synchronous and returns a `Message` object without the need to be `await`ed.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych when we don't use `await`, it only generate the "reply keyboard" on telegram bot and nothing else. It does not wait for the user to select an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that `python-telegram-bot` is *not* supporting `asyncio` natively for versions v13.x and earlier. `python-telegram-bot` *is* based on `asyncio` since version v20, which is currently in pre-release mode.
You can check which version you have installed by running `python -m telegram`.

Please also not that `await` -ing `reply_text` has nothing to do with waiting for user input. The `await` keyword in Python is purely related to the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) module.

If you want to have a conversation-like chat flow with the user, please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api).

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: So can you provide me with how to exactly wait for the user for input?
Thank you!

Comment: I already pointed you to the relevant question

Comment: Yep! I have seen it, Thanks!