# python-telegram-bot: Is there a way to ask different questions and save the results in a List?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am coding a Bot in **PyCharm** using the library **python-telegram-bot** and I am trying to collect the results from telegram users in a list. I need to ask the user their opinion about different topics. For example:

- Question1: Do you like art?
- Question 2: Do you like culture?
- […]

**The Bot should display the questions in the InLineKeyboard with two buttons to choose between the options “TRUE” or “FALSE”. The answers of the user shoueld be stored in a list called “number_list”**

This is my code for that part:

```
async def list_button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    # Get the data from the callback_data.
    # If you're using a type checker like MyPy, you'll have to use typing.cast
    # to make the checker get the expected type of the callback_data
    number, number_list = cast(Tuple[int, List[int]], query.data)
    # append the number to the list
    number_list.append(number)

    # List with categories
    data=['art','culture','sports']

    # Iterate categories each time when asking for reply
    for i in data:
        await query.edit_message_text(
        text="Do you like {}? Choose if True or False: So far..{}".format(i,number_list),
        reply_markup=build_keyboard(number_list),
        )

    # we can delete the data stored for the query, because we've replaced the buttons
    context.drop_callback_data(query)
```

When running the command “/start” (see below) it works fine with the first question. But after pressing one button, the following sentences of the loop shown above, are displayed very fast in a row and only stop with the last item of the "data" list (which is ‘sports’). This happens every time that I press a button.

```
async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> None:
    """Sends a message with 5 inline buttons attached."""
    number_list: List[int] = []
    await update.message.reply_text("Do you like nature? Choose if True or False:", reply_markup=build_keyboard(number_list))

def build_keyboard(current_list: List[int]) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    """Helper function to build the next inline keyboard."""
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup.from_column(
        [InlineKeyboardButton(str(i), callback_data=(i, current_list)) for i in ('True', 'False')]
    )
```

How can I fix this? Is there a way to ask different questions and save the results in a list?
Please note: I am using the Example of the telegram-bot wiki as inspiration: https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0b0/examples.arbitrarycallbackdatabot.html

And this is the complete code of my Bot:

```
import logging
from typing import List, Tuple, cast
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup, Update
from telegram.ext import (
    Application,
    CallbackQueryHandler,
    CommandHandler,
    ContextTypes,
    InvalidCallbackData,
    PicklePersistence,
)


# Enable logging
logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


async def start(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> None:
    """Sends a message with 5 inline buttons attached."""
    number_list: List[int] = []
    await update.message.reply_text("Do you like nature? Choose if True or False:", reply_markup=build_keyboard(number_list))

def build_keyboard(current_list: List[int]) -> InlineKeyboardMarkup:
    """Helper function to build the next inline keyboard."""
    return InlineKeyboardMarkup.from_column(
        [InlineKeyboardButton(str(i), callback_data=(i, current_list)) for i in ('True', 'False')]
    )

async def list_button(update: Update, context: ContextTypes) -> None:
    """Parses the CallbackQuery and updates the message text."""
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    # Get the data from the callback_data.
    # If you're using a type checker like MyPy, you'll have to use typing.cast
    # to make the checker get the expected type of the callback_data
    number, number_list = cast(Tuple[int, List[int]], query.data)
    # append the number to the list
    number_list.append(number)
    
    # List with categories
    data=['art','culture','sports']
    
    # Iterate categories each time when asking for reply
    for i in data:
        await query.edit_message_text(
        text="Do you like {}? Choose if True or False: So far..{}".format(i,number_list),
        reply_markup=build_keyboard(number_list),
        )

    # we can delete the data stored for the query, because we've replaced the buttons
    context.drop_callback_data(query)


TOKEN = 'XY'

def main() -> None:
    """Run the bot."""
    # We use persistence to demonstrate how buttons can still work after the bot was restarted
    persistence = PicklePersistence(filepath="arbitrarycallbackdatabot")
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = (
        Application.builder()
        .token(TOKEN)
        .persistence(persistence)
        .arbitrary_callback_data(True)
        .build()
    )

    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(list_button))

    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling(stop_signals=None) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: One way to solve this issue would be to update the loop in the list_button function so that it only iterates through the items in the data list once, rather than repeatedly executing the loop every time a button is pressed. You can do this by using a counter variable to keep track of which question you are currently on, and using an if statement to check if the counter has reached the end of the data list before displaying the next question.

Comment: Thank you @Dexty I have tried this but it is not working: 
    data=['art','culture','sports']
    counter=0
    # Iterate categories each time when asking for reply
    for i in data:
        if (counter+1) != len(data):
            await query.edit_message_text(
            text="Do you like {}? Choose if True or False: So far..{}".format(i,number_list),
            reply_markup=build_keyboard(number_list),
            )
        counter += 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)

Comment: Thank you @CallMeStag. I found another way to achieve my goal using context.user_data. It retrieves a dictionary with the user replies that I can store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed the approach and instead of using `update.callback_query` I have used `context.user_data` to save the answers of the questions.

Using `context.user_data` in a Handler callback, I have access to a user dictionary. I have passed a function to the results of the dictionary and it worked!

This bot example from python-telegram-bot wiki was really helpful for me, to find out a way to save data from the user. I hope it helps others:

https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/v20.0b0/examples.persistentconversationbot.html