# How to take input from the user in the python-telegram-bot module via telegram?

Tags: python, api, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I want to take input from the user in telegram without the backslash '/'.
After calling one command with '/', the user should be able to talk to the bot normally.

Example:
user: /start
bot: How can I help you?
user: /coding
bot: select your language c++ or java?
user: java
bot: Here are some resources for java:-

Note: In the fifth line user said 'java' and not '/java'.

I tried calling the "MessageHandler" inside the command function but its not working.

```
def reply_coding(updater, context):
    answer = updater.message.text
    updater.message.reply_text(f"{answer} selected")


def coding(updater, context):
    updater.message.reply_text("Select your language, c++ or java")
    dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.MessageHandler(telegram.ext.Filters.text, reply_coding))


dispatcher.add_handler(telegram.ext.CommandHandler("coding", coding))
```

Comment: you can use Conversations for that, see [conversationbot.py](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/examples.html#examples-conversationbot) for example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)

Answer (score 0):

Use ConversationHandler.
Check [this](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).