# How to get input from the user and show that at the end in python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am new to coding a telegram bot, and I am using the `python-telegram-bot` library to do that.

I want to code a bot that gets some input from the user and returns them at the end. e.g. below state:

The user sends the command: `/set_username`

Bot sends the text: `Enter the username:`

The user sends the username as a text: `negar-amiri`

Bot sends the text: `Username that you set is:\nnegar-amiri`

I Wrote the code below that gets only the file path correctly and no matter which command I send to it the bot always puts the answer in the `self.file_path` variable.

I found this problem because all the `MessageHandler`s have the same filters and no matter what command the user selects every message that is not a command goes into the `self.file_path` variable but I do not know how to fix it. Can you help me, please?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import (
    filters,
    ConversationHandler,
    Application,
    MessageHandler,
    CommandHandler,
)
import config

BOT_API_TOKEN = config.BOT_API_TOKEN

logging.basicConfig(
    format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.INFO
)
logging.getLogger("httpx").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class TelegramBot:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.file_path: str = ""
        self.username: str = ""
        self.password: str = ""
        self.host: str = ""

    async def start_command(self, update: Update) -> None:
        user = update.effective_user
        await update.message.reply_html(f"Hi {user.mention_html()}!")

    async def set_file_path_command(self, update: Update) -> int:
        self.file_path = update.message.text
        await update.message.reply_html(
            f"File address that you set is:\n{self.file_path}"
        )
        return ConversationHandler.END

    async def set_username_command(self, update: Update) -> int:
        self.username = update.message.text
        await update.message.reply_html(f"Username that you set is:\n{self.username}")
        return ConversationHandler.END

    async def set_password_command(self, update: Update) -> int:
        self.password = update.message.text
        await update.message.reply_html(f"Password that you set is:\n{self.password}")
        return ConversationHandler.END

    async def set_host_command(self, update: Update) -> int:
        self.host = update.message.text
        await update.message.reply_html(f"Host that you set is:\n{self.host}")
        return ConversationHandler.END

    async def echo_set_file_path(self, update: Update) -> None:
        await update.message.reply_text("Enter the file path:")

    async def echo_set_username(self, update: Update) -> None:
        await update.message.reply_text("Enter the username:")

    async def echo_set_password(self, update: Update) -> None:
        await update.message.reply_text("Enter the password:")

    async def echo_set_host(self, update: Update) -> None:
        await update.message.reply_text(
            "Enter the host(IP or URL e.g. 192.168.1.4 or test.com):"
        )

    async def end_command(self, update: Update) -> None:
        await update.message.reply_html(
            f"You Enter '{self.file_path}' as a file path.\nYou Enter '{self.username}' as a username.\nYou Enter '{self.password}' as a password.\nYou Enter '{self.host}' as a host."
        )


def main() -> None:
    application = Application.builder().token(BOT_API_TOKEN).build()
    bot = TelegramBot()
    application.add_handlers(
        [
            CommandHandler("start", bot.start_command),
            CommandHandler("end", bot.end_command),
            CommandHandler("set_file_path", bot.echo_set_file_path),
            CommandHandler("set_username", bot.echo_set_username),
            CommandHandler("set_password", bot.echo_set_password),
            CommandHandler("set_host", bot.echo_set_host),
            MessageHandler(
                filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND,
                bot.set_file_path_command,
            ),
            MessageHandler(
                filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND,
                bot.set_username_command,
            ),
            MessageHandler(
                filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND,
                bot.set_password_command,
            ),
            MessageHandler(
                filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND,
                bot.set_host_command,
            ),
        ]
    )
    application.run_polling(allowed_updates=Update.ALL_TYPES)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried some code but it did not work how I wanted.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you send your username as text, you will trigger the first

```
MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, bot.set_file_path_command)
```

which will execute the `set_file_path_command`. python-telegram-bot will work through the handlers sequentially and takes the first one matching the incoming message. In your code the MessageHandlers all match the same input, so it just takes the first one.

Eather you use more sophisticated filters or you look into conversationhandlers, e.g. https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/examples/conversationbot.py

With ConversationHandlers you can build entire conversations and handle different states within the conversation.