# How can a python telegram bot make a "double response" in a command

Tags: python, command, telegram, response, python-telegram-bot

I have this code where i created a telegram bot using the python telegram bot api. I have a command named "musica" (because i am italian) where if a person write /musica and a link of youtube the bot sends the mp3 file of that video. The code works but i want to make the bot saying "send a youtube link" when i write /musica, and after that he listens for a new message with the link. in a shorter way, i'm asking how to make a function for a command wait end analyze the next message, sorry for my bad english.
This is the main code: (download is the file where is stored the function ottieniMp3 that downloads the mp3)

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import Application, CommandHandler, filters, ContextTypes, MessageHandler
from download import ottieniMp3

token = "MYTOKEN"
username= "USERNAME"

#commands
async def musica(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    text= update.message.text.replace("/musica ", "")
    await update.message.reply_audio(open( ottieniMp3(text), "rb"))
#answers
def gestisciRisposte(text):
    return "i do not understand"
#messages managing
async def gestisciMessaggio(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    text = update.message.text
    answer= gestisciRisposte(text)
    await update.message.reply_text(answer)
async def gestisciErrore(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    print(f"Update {update} caused the error {context.error}")
#bot
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('the bot is starting')
    bot = Application.builder().token(token).build()
    #commands
    bot.add_handler(CommandHandler('musica', musica))
    #messages
    bot.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT, gestisciMessaggio))
    #errors
    bot.add_error_handler(gestisciErrore)

    print('Polling')
    #polling
    bot.run_polling(poll_interval = 3)
```

i've tried seeing on other sites but i didn't find what i was searching for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get several inputs in one command in telegram bot api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68142791/how-to-get-several-inputs-in-one-command-in-telegram-bot-api)